# Robotium : com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir

Tags: testing, gradle, robotium

> Input:
>
> C:\Users\Irvin\Desktop\Robotium\gradlew.bat -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
>   assembleDebugAndroidTest -u -b
>   C:\Users\Irvin\Desktop\Robotium\executorproject\build.gradle
>
> Output:
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.  * What went wrong: A
>   problem occurred configuring root project 'executorproject'. > Failed
>   to notify project evaluation listener.    >
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir(Ljava/io/File;)V
>   * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.  * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org  BUILD FAILED in 2s

What actually went wrong here ? I still cant figure it out for 3 days.